# Angular datatable dropdown value in table showing blank and value appears and disappears instantly when going to next paginated page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular10

The select option in the dropdown is showing blank value instead of selected value for each record. The foodCategories in child component is getting populated from parent component. It was working fine previously and only happened when migrated to **Angular** version 10.

Please note that form has also been properly initialized. What could be causing the issue?

`template.html` :

```
<table datatable  [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Food Name</th>
      <th>Food Description</th>
      <th>Food Category</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody *ngIf="food?.length != 0" id="thedatatable">
    <tr *ngFor="let food of foodList" id="{{food.Guid}}" class="alternate-row">
      <td><label>{{food.Name}}</label></td>
      <td><label>{{food.Description}}</label></td>
      <td>
        <form class="table_form" [formGroup]="tableForm            (ngSubmit)="onTableFormSubmit(tableForm.value)">
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="foodCategorySelect"
          (change)="onTableFormSubmit(tableForm.value, food.Guid)">
          <option *ngFor="let foodCategory of foodCategories" [value]="foodCategory.Guid"> {{foodCategory.CategoryName}}</option>
           </select>
         </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

`ts file` :

```
@Input() foodCategories: any[];
 ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
 if (changes.hasOwnProperty('foodCategories') &&    changes['foodCategories'].hasOwnProperty('currentValue')) {
        this.foodCategories = changes['foodCategories']['currentValue'];
        jQuery('.table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }
}
```

Value should reflect record value fetched from db.please help

Comment: `ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges):`. You can simply import `SimpleChnages` at the top of the file

Comment: @brk, yes but that is not what is causing the issue, right? foodcategories is getting populated from parent component. u think that is causing the prob?

Comment: What library are you using? [Here's](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/advanced/datatables) a purely angular datatable [code](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps%2Fng-bootstrap-demo%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fpages%2Fadvanced%2Fdatatables)